# When parsing, how to split string object then pull out last element (Python)

Tags: python

I'm doing a project in Python right now where we are supposed to parse the HTML from a Project Gutenberg file to isolate the book's contents. I've managed to get rid of everything except the Table of Contents. I want to remove the Table of Contents by making the soup.prettify() a string object, splitting it on the last phrase of the Table of Contents, and pulling the last element out of the list, which will be everything except for the table of contents. This is what I have so far.

```
 def get_text(): #writes the html into a new text file called new_christie.txt
        with open('new_christie.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') as book:
        url = 'http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1155/1155-h/1155-h.htm'
        r = requests.get(url)
        data = r.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
        str = soup.prettify()
        text = str.split('XXVIII.     AND AFTER') #last phrase in Table of Contents
        text = soup.find_all('p') #finds all of the text between paragraphs
        content = text[-1:]
        for p in content:
            line = p.get_text()
            book.write(line)
```

I think my problem lies in when I try to pull the last element out of the list using content = text[-1:], but I can't figure out another way to do it.

Comment: Did you try using just `text[-1]` without the colon

Comment: When I tried that, it deleted the entire text.

Comment: Also, is the string you picked for split a constant found in all Gutenberg entries? Or will your solution work only for a few entries that happen to look like this?

Comment: It should only work in this entry - we had to use this specific Agatha Christie book on Gutenberg, so it wouldn't be relevant anywhere else.

Comment: You don't actually use the result of the `split`....

Answer (score 0):

I offer this solution, except note that I use lxml instead of beautiful soup because I know it better. I don't remember if it is natively installed, but you can install it with `pip install lxml` in your terminal.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

def get_text():
    with open('new_christie.txt','w') as book:
        url = 'http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1155/1155-h/1155-h.htm'
        r = requests.get(url)
        data = r.text
        soup = html.fromstring(data.encode('utf8'))
        text = ' '.join(soup.xpath('//p/text()'))
        text = text.partition('AND AFTER')[2]
        book.write(text)
```